# no less + adjective

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

If we describe something or someone as "no less + adj.," does it mean they are described as "being +adj. to a great extent," or are they described as "being + adj. to some extent"?

One example:

> Marcus Aurelius is also known by many as a persecutor of Christians, in large part due to the record of John Foxe’s Book of Martyrs, which states, “Marcus Aurelius, followed about the year of our Lord 161, a man of nature more stern and severe; and, although in study of philosophy and in civil government **no less commendable**, yet, toward the Christians sharp and fierce; by whom was moved the fourth persecution.

Comment: I can't parse that "sentence". I can't find a main verb in the quoted portion. Did you copy it all correctly? In any case, normally, I can tell you that, "no less commendable" means "at least as commendable".

Comment: Here's the source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Marcus-Aurelius.html

Comment: In other sources, there's no comma after "Marcus Aurelius," so that the sentence reads, "Marcus Aurelius followed about the year of our Lord 161, a man of nature more stern and severe..."

Comment: Does the portion of the sentence mean ""at least as commendable as other people"?

Comment: That's a quote from [a book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxe%27s_Book_of_Martyrs) published in 1563. I have no idea what it means.